# What is the reason for an increase of back-pressure of HPLC column?

Tags: chromatography

Recently i have observed that the back pressure in my HPLC reverse phase column increased almost twice, and sometimes after sample injection the pressure increased so high that removed the connector of column. 
What is the reason for that, even though I am using HPLC grade solvents, In my point of view may be some impurities stuck inside. I have washed my column with methanol for long but it's seems useless. 
Is there anything which can i do to solve this problem, because the column is expensive and don't have funds in lab to buy another one.

Comment: Replace the precolumn filter frit, perhaps? That's the first place I would look and the one with the least expensive fix. If you're not using a precolumn filter, by all means do so from now on.

Comment: @ToddMinehardt, thanks for your comment, appreciated

Comment: When you say almost twice, what does that actually mean? You can get a pressure spike during injection as the valve switches to put the sample on the column. If your initial solvent system is too viscous or flow rate too high, the back pressure may be running high anyway. Using a KrudKatcher or guard forum is good advice.  If yes don't fix your problem and you have the ability to automate a gradient,  halve your flow rate for the first  5-10 seconds so your initial conditions halve your back pressure.  Once the injection spike passes, the full flow rate can be used.